# My 2007 Ford Focus feels like an SUV going around curves. Why?

Tags: suspension, corolla, focus

My wife has a 2007 Ford Focus and I have a 1997 Toyota Corolla. The reviews I read of the 2007 (and similar years) Focus say that it's actually pretty fun to drive, but personally I hate it. It just feels so top-heavy. Going around a curve feels like driving an SUV, like I'm worried it's going to roll over (body roll isn't particularly bad, it just *feels* bad). Driving around in my boring old Corolla is much more fun and feels so much better. I can take a turn in my Corolla that would make me feel like I was going to slide right off the road in the Focus. (I've never lost grip going around a turn, it just *feels* like I will.)

Are the reviews right and this a symptom of something wrong with the suspension? Worn shocks/struts maybe? Is there anything I can do to fix it? Or is everything fine and it's just that I'm used to sitting a couple inches closer to the ground in the Corolla?

Comment: What are the tires you have on it (brand and size)? Are these OEM tires? Is this a sport version of the Focus or a base version?

Comment: It's the SES trim, which from what I've read means it's got 16" wheels (base has 15") and a rear sway bar. Other than that the suspension is the same as the base version.

Comment: So then, what are the tires (brand and size - to include all parameters) of the ones on car right now? Are these OEM tires?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 they're Primewell Valera Sport AS, P205/50R16.

Comment: Have your suspension checked at the service station